# Google Maps - Heatmap Layer is Behind The Data Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization, visualization

I'm close to achieving what I need in this map, I added a Heatmap layer to show heat maps and a Data layer to draw polygons from the geojson data.
If you take a closer look in the image below, you can see the heatmaps are hidden behind the polygons,, All I need is some help to bring the Heatmap layer to Top.
Thanks in Advance! :)

[image: Google Map with Heatmap layer and Data layer]

And This is the result if I reduce the opacity of polygons, but heatmap layer is still behind so its just not enough :/

[image: Result with lower opacity of data layer polygons]

Following is the Code I'm using:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 37.0902 , lng: -95.7129},
    zoom: 4 });

map.data.loadGeoJson('http://localhost/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json');

var heatMapData = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447), weight: 3},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(46.965260, -109.533691), weight: 3},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(40.273502, -86.126976), weight: 1},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(38.573936, -92.603760), weight: 9},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(27.994402, -81.760254), weight: 2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(39.876019, -117.224121), weight: 9},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(45.367584, -68.972168), weight: 4},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(44.182205, -84.506836), weight: 6},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.247875, -83.441162), weight: 1},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(21.289373, -157.917480), weight: 8},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(66.160507, -153.369141), weight: 3},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(35.860119, -86.660156), weight: 9},
];

heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatMapData,
  map: map
});
```

Comment: Give us some code of how you get, initialise add your heatmap etc .. to your map

Comment: I edited the question and added the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to set the `zIndex` of the data layer using the `setStyle` method. You can even apply a different `zIndex` to each feature [if you pass it a function as argument](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.StylingFunction).

However, every data layer that your map contains is rendered inside a div which is a child of the overlayLayer (see [MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapPanes)). Modifying the zIndex of a data layer **will only modify its relative index vs other data layers**. The div in question will still have its own z-index (in my case it's 30).

The HeatmapLayer will be rendered inside another div in the overlayLayer, which in my case has a z-index of 15.

[image]

You can set the data layer z-index to -100 if you want, but its parent element z-index trumps the heatmap parent element's z-index.

Now, here's a **hacky and dirty way** of doing what you want.

1.- Create an auxiliar [google.maps.OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView) to get a reference to the map panes.

```
var auxOverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
auxOverlay.draw = function () {};
auxOverlay.onAdd = function () {};
```

2.- set the map property of the OverlayView.

```
auxOverlay.setMap(map);
```

3.- Get a reference to the `overlayLayer` pane and add an ID to it. I will use jQuery. Probably someone will say it can be done with vanilla JS. Okay, but I will do it with jQuery.

```
jQuery(auxOverlay.getPanes().overlayLayer).attr('id','overlayLayer')
```

4.- When no custom overlay has been added to the map the data layer will be the only content of the 'overlayLayer', so you can give it an ID

```
jQuery('#overlayLayer > div').first().attr('id','datalayer');
```

[image]

5.- Now you have a reference to the datalayer container so, once you add your heatmap, you can use the reference to the datalayer container to put it below your Heatmap

[image]

For example, doing

```
jQuery('#datalayer').css('z-index',10);
```

Will put it below the heatmap.

**Hacky as hell** and of course not scalable if you wanted to juggle with other kinds of layers.

Comment: woooooyyeaaahh!!!, its dirty but it works, and the fact that I dont need additional data layers, this way is cool for me, 

Thanks!

Comment: auxOverlay.getPanes() was returning undefined for me, so I just used a timer+function to check when it was not undefined anymore and then I could change the z-index and add my 2nd layer